# Test extends Activity implements onClickListener, when/where does the instance of class "Test" created?

Tags: android, interface, instance, onclicklistener

In the following code, the class "Test" is extends Acitivity and implements OnClickListener.

but, the "this" refer to the instance of class "Test". There is no "new" to create
a new object to class "Test".  So, where/when the instance of Test class created?

```
public class Test extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button playButton;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     playButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);

     playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Thanks for anyone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android framework is instantiating your activities for you when you open new intents, that's why you don't need to do `new ActivityClass`, all you have to do is declare your activities in your `AndroidManifest`.

> So, where/when the instance of Test class created?

The instance is created 'internally', somewhere between `openIntent` and `onCreate` methods.

Comment: No book or forum discuss the above case. Therefore, many Android beginners confuse about "this is refer to the current object of the class"!

Comment: Yeah, the last sentence is actually true, that just doesn't mean there must be a `new` on sight :)

Answer (score 1):

> So, where/when the instance of Test class created?

On calling `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method ( in your case) since its main Activity

To make it more clear, lets change a bit your code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     playButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);

      OnClickListener clickListener = this; // take current instance

     playButton.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}
```

We register our Activity to listener by passing instance to listen on events. however we don't want that `setOnClickListener` will see all our methods so they ask us to provide Interface only (`OnClickListener`).

Comment: Actually, `setOnClickListener` won't see `Test` methods, as its param is declared as `View.OnClickListener`.

Comment: Sure, because we pass only interface

Comment: Mmh still don't see the point in `OnClickListener clickListener = this;`, afaik passing just `this` to `setOnClickListener` will have the same effect.

Comment: When you pass `this` its not clear for programmer what actually you pass. Sometimes I see in code like: `foo(this, this, this)`. My example demonstrates what Interface you use from current instance `this` and pass it to listener